# My website is throwing "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Lang::lang()"

Tags: codeigniter

I created a website using CodeIgniter Framework 2.1.0 that was originally working well. Yesterday, I integrated [this i18n code](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n) into the site for multi-language support. 
Now, when I upload my site to cpanel and open it, I get this error in my log file:

> [21-Nov-2011 10:19:04] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CI_Lang::lang() in XXXX

However, the website is working well on my localhost server (xampp for Windows). What's wrong?

Comment: The method `CI_Lang::lang()` doesn't exist. You should ask the question on CodeIgniter's forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the thread attached to the library: http://web.archive.org/web/20120112092127/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179036. In the first post is attached a modified library that claims to alleviate the buggyness of the original.

There is also a post on the first page there referencing an error similar to yours:

> After copying the files as described in the article I get the
>   following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CI_Lang::CI_Lang() in
>   /www/websites/audio-machinery/application/core/MY_Lang.php on line 32

Though he seems to be calling CI_Lang, not Lang. His solution appears to have been to use the code attached to the forum thread.

Also, cpanel is a control panel for hosting, not a hosting provider. But your hosting provider may be causing issues (e.g. if using older versions of PHP which do not work with newer version of CI. Often hosting providers will give you the ability to choose which version of PHP you are using--usually found in cPanel).

Comment: @ThiefMaster there is no fix. Do as you see fit.

Comment: @RahulChipad Yeah, sorry, the link is broken and there is no working alternative.

Comment: I also having same problem with php 7

Comment: @RobbNesp I found a working link and updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 1):

have you uploaded ALL the new files to your live server? that error implies that the code is not found or available to the script.

Comment: Yes i have upload all the files on my server, 4 times.

Comment: if its working in your local dev server, and you are sure you have copied all the files to the live server, then next bet would be to check your PHP environment..

Comment: just a thought, check your FTP transfer settings.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross the same problem.... it was working fine on localhost but when loaded on live server it gives me undefined error... the problem appears becuase I created file with name My_Lang.php and My_Config.php as on live server it is case sensitive.... so I changed it to MY_Config.php and MY_Lang.php .... it works fine now.... Hope it will work for you too